# My asynchronous javascript gets executed in the middle of the other function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, promise, callback

Im trying to execute a function after the other one in Vue.js. I've already tried async/await, callback functions, .then, but it somehow doesnt want to load one after the other. What is a possible solution?

auth_mixin.js:

```
async auth () {
            console.log("authban")
            var token = this.getCookie("token")
            var jsonData = {}
            jsonData["token"] = token
            console.log(jsonData)
            var bodyFormData = new FormData();
            bodyFormData.append('data', JSON.stringify(jsonData));
            axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'backend/index.php?action=checkAuth',
                    data: bodyFormData,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                      console.log(response);
                      if(response.data.status==="OK"){
                        console.log("ok")
                        return true;
                      }else{
                        console.log("nem ok")
                        return false;
                      }
                    })
                    .catch(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        return false;
                    });
           }
```

Navbar.vue:

```
created () {
    var result=false
    this.auth().then(this.checkIfLoggedIn(result))
  },
  methods: {
      checkIfLoggedIn (isLoggedIn) {
        console.log("na ez lesz az erdekes   "+isLoggedIn)
      if(isLoggedIn === true){
        console.log("true")
        document.getElementById("logged_out").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("logged_in").style.display="block";
      }else{
        console.log("fail");
      }
    }
  }
```

[image: Order of execution]

Comment: first obvious issue ... issue, `.then` expects a function as an argument, anything else is ignored (in this case executed immediately) - another issue, why use `var result = false` and pass `result` to `this.checkIfLoggedIn` rather than just `this.checkIfLoggedIn(false)` - since that is the only thing your code will ever pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> this.auth().then(this.checkIfLoggedIn(result))
> ```

You have two problems.

First: `this.checkIfLoggedIn(result)` calls `checkIfLoggedIn` **immediately**. You need to pass a function to `then`.

```
this.auth().then(() => this.checkIfLoggedIn(result))
```

Second: With that change, you call `checkIfLoggedIn` when `auth` resolves.

So when does `auth` resolve? Well, it is defined with the `async` keyword, so it resolves when it `returns` (unless it returns a promise, in which case it adopts that promise instead).

So what does it return? It has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined` when it gets to the end … which is immediately after the call to `axios` (since you aren't `await`ing that).

If you `return`ed the return value of `axios(...).etc` then it wouldn't resolve until *that* promise resolved.

(Aside: You're using `async`, you should probably refactor to use `await`, `try {} catch() {}` instead of `.then()` and `.catch()`).

Comment: Thank you so much, i completely get it now!